# What is purpose of "::" before a "-webkit" css declaration

Tags: css, webkit

Recently I read a CSS declaration that started with `::`. Can you tell me its purpose?

Example:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width:0;
}
```

It is used [here](http://www.designmadeingermany.de) for example.

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS statement

Comment: for others with this question, read this: http://www.impressivewebs.com/before-after-css3/ after the W3C Specs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a [CSS pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements).
The `::` is part of the selector, just like `:` is part of the `:focus` selector.

Comment: `::` by itself is nothing.  Your question is equivalent to asking what the letter `a` is good for.

Comment: Cant you post a link or give some more details. When it is used and for that kind of selector its used. I don't get it.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements   ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/